# Algorithm or data structure for ordering and grouping list elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

For example, say I have a drop down menu, and these are the first three options:

```
optionA
optionB
optionC
```

And when the user chooses optionA, I want more options to become available based upon that choice.

```
optionA --> suboptionA1
       |--> suboptionA2
       |---> suboptionA3
```

and if they were to choose optionB instead, I want different suboptions, even though some suboptions may belong to both like in this example where suboptionA1 is still a suboption for optionB:

```
optionB --> suboptionA1
       |--> suboptionB1
       |--> suboptionB2
```

and the list can continue on in this manner...

```
optionB --> suboptionB2 --> moreoption1
                       |--> moreoption2
                       |--> suboptionA1
```

Is there an algorithm or data structure that is good for this sort of representation? Where ordering of the options matters, and some options can belong to more than one parent option.

Comment: looks like a decision tree

Comment: Note that Algorithm and data structure work together and they use each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a drop down menu and there are a user interaction so i support that your application is a kind of web or gui application.

if you use a database you can store the Tree/Graph options and suboptions in One table or 2 tables.

If you can't use a database you can create a graph data structure and associated algorithm to manipulate it depending on your graph implementation array, pointer.. .

in Java Programming language:

```
class Option {
...
List<Option> childOptions;// or Option[] childOptions;
// and you can keep a list of parents too
List<Option> parentOptions;
...
}
```

**Note that Algorithm and Data structure work together and they use each other.**

In C Programming language:

```
struct Option {
...
Option *childOption[]; // option has many childs.
Option *parentOption[]; // option has many parents.
};
```

option *root;

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct option {
        option *sub = NULL, *next = NULL;
    };

    option *root;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct Option {
    int isLeaf;
    struct Option* suboptionA;
    struct Option* suboptionB;
    struct Option* suboptionC;
} Option;

Option* curr = rootOption; // this is the root of your decision tree
while (curr) {
    if (curr->isLeaf){
        // this is the end of your decision tree
    } else {
        Option* selectedOption = getSelectionFromCurr(curr); // this method would display suboptions and return a selection.
        curr = selectedOption;
    }
}
```